# Code Suggestions stopped Working (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, intellisense

After creating a new Flutter Project in VSCode/Android Studio, there are just no code suggestions. Pressing ctrl+space usually brought up suggestions in both, but now on Android Studio it says no suggestions, and on VSCode I get the usual few snippets, no IntelliSense.

Weird thing is when I tried reopening previous projects, some projects are still fine, some projects have the same issue. I have attached screenshots of when it works, and when it doesn't

[image]

[image]

PS: I'm not sure if this is related but in VSCode just when a new project is made it fails to recognise the header file so it highlights everything as Error though the code runs fine. However this gets fixed when the window is reloaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens when your IDE is not sync with the version of Dart and/or Flutter used in the project ; that's why on some projects it still works, and not on the other.

**Option 1** :

Try to update your Dart/Flutter version on the project, and on the plugin/extension of the IDE. Watch out to have the last version of your IDE, not on beta channel, as well.

**Option 2** :

If still not working after the update, delete IDE related files in problematic projects and reopen them.

Last time worked for me, hope it will for you !

Comment: Yeah flutter upgrade worked. So is it that the flutter plugin made a new flutter project that targeted a newer sdk version than what I had? Was that the problem

Comment: Problem is that :
- IDE use a plugin/extension that use its own Flutter version
- your project is IDE free, and use its own Flutter version (installed trough command line probably)

==> if those versions are not the same, IDE is having hard times to display code-completion.

If my answer worked, please mark it as 'resolved' so other people have the answer too :)

Comment: What are IDE related files?

Comment: removing .idea folder in case android studio and restarting it worked! Thanks